# unique chat records sql

Tags: sql-server, chat, filtering

I have `DB` which having 5 column as follows:

- message_id
- user_id_send
- user_id_rec
- message_date
- message_details

Looking for a SQL Serve Query, I want to Filter Results from two columns (`user_id_send`,`user_id_rec`)for Given User ID based on following constrains:

- Get the Latest Record (filtered on date or message_id)
- Only Unique Records (1 - 2 , 2 - 1 are same so only one record will be returned which ever is the latest one)
- Ordered by Descending based on message_id

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWNP.png)

The main purpose of this query is to get records of user_id to find out to whom he has sent messages and from whom he had received messages.

I have also attached the [sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka7yd1bgc6c1awa/ChatQuery.xlsx?dl=0) for your reference.

Here is my try

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   messages 
         WHERE  user_id_sender = 1) 
SELECT DISTINCT user_id_reciever, 
                * 
FROM   t; 

WITH h 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   messages 
         WHERE  user_id_reciever = 1) 
SELECT DISTINCT user_id_sender, 
                * 
FROM   h;
```

[image]

Comment: Everything looks good expect the missing query. Can you add whatever you have tried so far to solve the problem

Comment: @VR46 here is what I right... but not getting results as expected. `with t as (select * from messages where user_id_Sender = 1) select distinct user_id_reciever,* from t;
with h as (select * from messages where user_id_reciever = 1) select distinct user_id_sender,* from h;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH tmpMsg AS (
SELECT M2.message_id
              ,M2.user_id_receiver
              ,M2.user_id_sender
              ,M2.message_date
              ,M2.message_details
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY     user_id_receiver+user_id_sender ORDER BY message_date DESC) AS 'RowNum'
          FROM messages M2
         WHERE M2.user_id_receiver = 1
            OR M2.user_id_sender = 1
)
SELECT T.message_id
      ,T.user_id_receiver
      ,T.user_id_sender
      ,T.message_date
      ,T.message_details
  FROM tmpMsg T
 WHERE RowNum <= 1
```

The above should fetch you the results you are looking for when you query for a particular user_id (replace the 1 with parameter e.g. @p_user_id). The user_id_receiver+user_id_sender in the PARTITION clause ensure that records with user id combinations such as 1 - 2, 2 - 1 are not selected twice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just wondering if I can ask here for a sub requirement, or I have to start another thread? I want to join a `users` table where I have a Primary key `User_ID`, and both  `user_id_receiver,user_id_sender` are the foreign keys.

Comment: I think you can join the USERS table to the outer query. You may have to join it twice with distinct aliases for sender and receiver on the respective ids..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by message_date DESC) as rowno,
* from messages
where user_id_receiver = 1
--order by message_date DESC
) T where T.rowno = 1
UNION ALL
select * from 
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by message_date DESC) as rowno,
* from messages
where user_id_sender = 1
-- order by message_date DESC
) T where T.rowno = 1
```

Explanation: For each group of user_id_sender, it orders internally by message_date desc, and then adds row numbers, and we only want the first one (chronologically last). Then do the same for user_id_receiver, and union the results together to get 1 result set with all the desired rows. You can then add your own order by clause and additional where conditions at the end as required.

Of course, this only works for any 1 user_id at a time (replace `=1` with @user_id).

To get a result from all user_id's at once, is a totally different query, so I hope this helps?

Comment: getting these errors `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.` I have checked the other code. which is working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: The syntax and other errors have been corrected. I see you already accepted an answer, so just see this as an alternative solution.

Comment: Your efforts are really appreciating. :) Actually I have already incorporated the above code in my system.

Comment: 1. I enjoyed finding a solution for you 2. my technique is different than the @vmachan, so other SO users might find the differences educational.